# How to avoid postback for the ASP button click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery multiselect in that I am using button click event which goes the server side and the populates the values on the other dropdownlist. Based on the checked selection in the drop down list it populate the values in the other dropdownlist.

Issue:

For eg: in the first jQuery multiselect dropdown if I select 3 values and close the dropdownlist based on these three values checked the details are fetched in the other jQuery multiselect dropdownlist but the last checked value only is checked and that is retaining. I think it is because of button click event it occurs a asynchronous postback and the values is not retaining. Is their any option to prevent that postback in the button click event but the click should be called then only the values will be retained.

For these I am attaching the screen shot:

[image]

Based on that three values it is loaded in the other dropdownlist but it is shows "1 selected" that is default "Select".

[image]

But the second dropdownlist I can able to get the values that is checked in the first dropdown list:

[image]

this is my javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.department').multiselect({
                show: ["bounce", 5], hide: ["blind", 1],

                close: function () {
                    debugger;
                    var values = new Array();

                    $(this).multiselect("getChecked").each(function (index, item) {
                        values.push($(item).val());
                    });
                    $("input[id*=selectedValues]").val(values.join(","));
                    document.getElementById("<%=hdnDepartment.ClientID %>").value = values;
                    if (document.getElementById("<%=hdnDepartment.ClientID %>").value != "") {
                        **$("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>")[0].click();**

                    }
                }

            })
        .multiselectfilter();
        });

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Populate();
    }
```

Correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: Show markup. Did you add `multiple="multiple"` attribute to dropdowns?

Comment: that's was a tip. Just add `multiple="true"` attribute to dropdowns markup

Comment: no not working i have tried it

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnClientClick and return false or true as per your requirement.
When OnClientClick return true postback will occur else no postback

Comment: that button event i am calling only in the script the button is display none.

Comment: You can modify this condition and make it true as per your requirement when you need to do the postback.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function pageLoad() {
           $("#<%= DepartmentsListBox.ClientID %>").multiselect({
                create: function () {
                     $(this).data("initValues", $.map($("option:selected", this), function (option) { return option.value; }).join(","));
                },
                close: function () {
                     var selectedValues = $.map($("option:selected", this), function (option) { return option.value; }).join(",");
                     if (selectedValues !== $(this).data("initValues")) {
                          __doPostBack("<%= DepartmentsListBox.UniqueID %>", "");
                     }
                }
           });

           $("#<%= EmployeesListBox.ClientID %>").multiselect();
      }
 </script>


 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="DepartmentsListBox" DataValueField="DepartmentId"
                SelectionMode="Multiple" DataTextField="Name" Width="300px"></asp:ListBox>
           <br />
           <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="EmployeesListBox" Width="300px" SelectionMode="Multiple" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                DataValueField="EmployeeId" DataTextField="Name"></asp:ListBox>
           <br />
           <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" />
      </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server code

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();

private string[] selectedDepartments;
private string[] SelectedDepartments
{
    get
    {
        return selectedDepartments ?? (selectedDepartments = DepartmentsListBox.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected).Select(item => item.Value).ToArray());
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmployeesListBox.PreRender += new EventHandler(EmployeesListBox_PreRender);
    DepartmentsListBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DepartmentsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDepartments();
    }
}

void EmployeesListBox_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (EmployeesListBox.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        EmployeesListBox.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
    }
    else
    {
        EmployeesListBox.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
    }
}

private void BindDepartments()
{
    var departments = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
        .Select(id => new { DepartmentId = id, Name = "Department " + id.ToString() });
    DepartmentsListBox.DataSource = departments;
    DepartmentsListBox.DataBind();
}

void DepartmentsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var employees = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
        .Select(id => new { EmployeeId = id, DepartmentId = rnd.Next(1, 10), Name = "Employee #" + id.ToString() })
        .Where(emp => SelectedDepartments.Contains(emp.DepartmentId.ToString())).ToList();

    for (int itemIndex = EmployeesListBox.Items.Count - 1; itemIndex >= 0; itemIndex--)
    {
        var employee = employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.EmployeeId.ToString() == EmployeesListBox.Items[itemIndex].Value);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            EmployeesListBox.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            employees.Remove(employee);
        }
    }

    EmployeesListBox.DataSource = employees;
    EmployeesListBox.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: i cant change this to listbox my client needs a check box only which is easy to check the values...