# How to call a webmethod in the jquery multislect

Tags: asp.net, jquery

when i am usung the  jquery multiselect close function i am calling a webmethod in the code behind the method is not hitting
my script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.department').multiselect({
        show: ["bounce", 5], hide: ["blind", 1],

        close: function () {
            debugger;
            var values = new Array();

            $(this).multiselect("getChecked").each(function (index, item) {
                values.push($(item).val());
            });
            $("input[id*=selectedValues]").val(values.join(","));
            document.getElementById("<%=hdnDepartment.ClientID %>").value = values;
            if (document.getElementById("<%=hdnDepartment.ClientID %>").value != "") {
                //$("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>")[0].click();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "wfrmLeave_PermisssionReport.aspx/Populate",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
    .multiselectfilter();
});
```

my method is:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public  void Populate()
{
    strQuery = "select * from tblhrims_employeedetail where  nvrresigned='No'";
    if (ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Select")
    {
        strQuery += "and nvrbusinessunit ='" + ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue + "' ";
    }
    if (hdnDepartment.Value != "")
    {
        string strDepartment = hdnDepartment.Value;
        string[] strarrDepartment = strDepartment.Split(',');
        strDepartment = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < strarrDepartment.Length; i++)
        {
            strDepartment += "'" + strarrDepartment[i] + "'" + ",";
        }
        strDepartment = strDepartment.TrimEnd(',');
        strQuery += "and nvrdepartment in(" + strDepartment + ")";
    }

    populateDropDown(strQuery, ddlEmployeeName, "nvrempname", "nvrempcode");
}
```

Comment: edit my code behind code i cant able to edit it

Comment: When you are using jQuery, why do you have to use  document.getElementById?

Comment: Watch out for SQL injections. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_Implementations

Comment: to check the hidden feild values is there are not...if not equal to null then going to ajax method to populate another dropdown in that POPULATE method

Comment: make the `Populate` method static. BTW, how many accounts you had created? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560655/how-to-avoid-postback-for-the-asp-button-click-event/12563394#12563394?

Comment: i cant change this to listbox my client needs a check box only which is easy to check the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this helps you http://trentgardner.net/net/asp-net-webmethods-with-jquery-and-ajax/